# Deadlock victim in ONLY ONE transaction process

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have written a stored procedure, which is working in a loop on a big table of financial data.

The procedure is reading a command table whch contains a lot of formulas. These formulas are translated into rather complex INSERT commands: Each insert command reads multiple lines from the file, then does math operations, and then creates a new line.

This looks like this:

```
"Formula": R411 = R22+R26*R22

insert into tab (RecNr, value) select 411, (select value from tab
where RecNr = 22) + (select value from tab where RecNr = 26)*(select
value from tab where RecNr = 22)
```

So far this runs very good, but sometimes, I suddenly get a DEADLOCK VICTIM error, and the procedure stops.

There are NO OTHER processes running which are using this table! 
Even more, the records which are inserted are NOT READ again during the procedure!

I only have two ideas:

- It might happen that an EXISTING record is READ multiple times within the SELECT part of the INSERT statement (like Record Nr 22 in my example)
- Also, I have the vague idea that SQL server might not doing a "RECORD LOCKING", but some kind od "PAGE LOCKING". Therefore, it might happen that the SQL server wants to insert a new record, but the page is locked from the reading operaton within the select statement.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Is there an index on `RecNr`? If not, your queries are performing table scans, which take a lot longer than index lookups. This is relevant because deadlocks are far more likely for long-running statements that perform a lot of locking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to track down the problem by creating a "deadlock graph" with the SQL Server profiler. You need to select the "deadlock graph" event in the profiler and then wait until the deadlock appears. Details can be found in the Microsoft MSDN online documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Run the query below to get more information about the deadlock from the system-health Extended Event session.  A deadlock requires more than one connection so I would expect other activity.

```
--get deadlock_report from ring_buffer target
SELECT
       xed.value('@timestamp', 'datetime') as Creation_Date,
       xed.query('.') AS Extend_Event
FROM
(
       SELECT CAST([target_data] AS XML) AS Target_Data
       FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS xt
       INNER JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions AS xs
       ON xs.address = xt.event_session_address
       WHERE xs.name = N'system_health'
       AND xt.target_name = N'ring_buffer'
) AS XML_Data
CROSS APPLY Target_Data.nodes('RingBufferTarget/event[@name="xml_deadlock_report"]') AS XEventData(xed)
ORDER BY Creation_Date DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you. I was then finally able to track the problem with the SQL Profiler Tool. And you are right: There was really a 2nd process involved in the deadlock!! It was an automatic job which was running every 5 minutes and doing some updates. This job actually was the result of some "quick hack" done some time ago, and I had not thought of this process anymore. Well, we have cleaned up this now.

Comment: FYI: sad but true, I've had a situation where we got deadlocks using just 1 connection. I believe it was on SQL2k at the time and the query was quite elaborate. What happened was that the Query Plan would split out the operation over different threads (all on the same spid) and then one thread somehow managed to deadlock another one causing the entire query to go 'boom'. At the time, adding MAXDOP 1 solved the issue but the client who had spent $$$ on his multi-cpu machine wasn't overly happy with it =) In the end it got fixed by MS (can't find KB article anymore, it's a long time ago)